# How can a closure in Swift only be passed in a * for the reduce function?

Tags: swift

```
extension Array {
func reduce<T>(_ initial: T, combine: (T, Element) -> T) -> T {
    var result = initial
    for x in self {
        result = combine(result, x)
    }
    return result
  }
 }
```

How does the below function work when it only passes a * to the combine closure?

```
func productUsingReduce(integers: [Int]) -> Int {
    return integers.reduce(1, combine: *)
}
```

Comment: The question title is a bit ambiguous: are you asking how to pass `*` to the function, or asking what happens if you do pass it to a function? If the latter, then simply view `*` as a function that takes two arguments and returns their product, i.e., `func multiply(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> T { lhs * rhs }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[static func * (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric/2883821) is an operator function defined on the [Numeric](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric) protocol. So, you are really just passing in a function that takes two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

What does the declaration mean?

```
combine: (T, Element) -> T
```

It says: the `combine` parameter is a function that takes two parameters, a T and an Element, and returns a T.

Well, in Swift, operators are functions, and `*` *is* such a function. So it suffices to pass a reference to this function as the `combine` parameter. The bare name, `*`, is that reference.